# Which server to set up for distribution of windows based application updates, patches and upgrades?

Tags: installation, upgrade

We are looking forward to set up some server to distribute application patches, updates, and upgrades. Our applications would be checking for their updates by querying this server. Presently, developers here are considering Chocolatey, and just rejected Squirrel for windows due to its narrow scope.

How is this being done in the world generally with best practices?

Comment: Are your servers hosted in the cloud? Are they all Windows servers?

Comment: Are you looking to provide windows updates or are you looking to provide updates for *applications* like Adobe, Firefox, Chrome, etc, or both? For windows updates, best practice is WSUS.

Comment: No, mostly we will be providing updates, patches, and upgrades for our applications, which are mostly delivered via Wix based MSI packages.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed How are your MSI packages built? How are they stored? Just trying to get a grasp so I can give you a concrete answer :)

Comment: @PrestonM. We are using TFS to build our code including installer packages. Presentley we are only giving links to our website to download them.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: not yet. Still distributing by uploading to our regular web site...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Chocolatey. There are more and more companies that are adopting this. For example, if one would like to install Gradle and navigates to the [installation page](https://gradle.org/install/):

> Chocolatey is “the package manager for Windows”.
>
> ```
> $ choco install gradle
> ```